# C# - Unhandled exception in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, exception, html-agility-pack

I get this error when I loop

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by the following scenario

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   collection.Add(newItem); // will set up the error
   collection.Remove(item); // will set up the error
}
```

The above code actually compiles to something like this:

```
IEnumerator iEnum = collection.GetEnumerator();

while (iEnum.GetNext())
{
  var item = iEnum.Current;

   collection.Add(newItem); // will set up the error
   collection.Remove(item); // will set up the error
}
```

You wont get the error until you try to get the next item (ie at the start of the next loop). If you modify any IEnumerable collection you need to leave the loop and not call the `GetNext()` member returned by the `IEnumerator` object returned by the `IEnumerable`

So if somewhere in your code, while executing, say the `Players` collection you do something that causes the `Players` collection to be modified you will get the error.

Comment: But I don't get why the initial run I make (as soon as i run the application) works. The error only occurs the second time it runs it (this time through the timer). How would I go ahead and solve this in my scenario, and leave the loop as in your example? is there perhaps an even better way of doing this without asyncs in the first place?

Comment: I don't get what I'm doing wrong in the second foreach loop (if that is the one you are referring to): `foreach (var character in Players)` All I do there is setting variables before inserting the data into my db